# Django Nginx, and Gunicorn .sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am newbie to Python Django, I have create my application successfully and when I try to host my Django application on Ubuntu 16.04 it is not working properly I tried several way and Google it a lot, Please help to escape from this.

I followed this URL [How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04) I have done everything set up properly but it still I didn't succeed on this. Here I share the necessary file for your reference please let me know if I missed out anything.

**etc/nginx/site-available**

```
server {
    listen *:91;
    server_name ip-address;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
            root /home/iradmin/django/scm;
    }
    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/iradmin/django/scm/scm.sock;
    }
}
```

**etc/inint/gunicorn.confi**

```
decription "Gunicorn application server handling scm"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
setuid iradmin
setgid www-data
chdir /home/iradmin/django/scm/
exec python3venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/iradmin/django/scm/scm.sock scm.wsgi:application
```

When I completed all the steps for deployment this the following error I am getting in nginx/error.log

```
2018/06/25 18:59:50 [crit] 32640#32640: *8 connect() to unix:/home/iradmin/django/scm/scm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.200.101.124, server: ip-address, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/iradmin/django/scm/scm.sock:/", host: "10.200.101.227:91"
2018/06/25 18:59:52 [crit] 32640#32640: *10 connect() to unix:/home/iradmin/django/scm/scm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.200.101.124, server: ip-address, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/iradmin/django/scm/scm.sock:/", host: "10.200.101.227:91"
[ N 2018-06-25 19:02:33.5097 32620/T4 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 32725, application /var/www/pyraMID (production)
```

This is my application structure
[image]

**Gunicorn status**

```
root@iradmin-OptiPlex-3040:/etc/init# sudo service gunicorn status
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-06-25 19:15:22 IST; 33min ago
 Main PID: 5226 (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)

Jun 25 19:15:22 iradmin-OptiPlex-3040 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jun 25 19:15:22 iradmin-OptiPlex-3040 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
Jun 25 19:15:22 iradmin-OptiPlex-3040 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 25 19:15:22 iradmin-OptiPlex-3040 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried several way but still I don't have any idea about the .sock file and how to create that? I really thank for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

File '.sock' will get created automatically with proper configurations. No need to create it manually. Give absolute of gunicorn in **etc/inint/gunicorn.confi** file

```
exec python3venv/bin/gunicorn
```

should be

```
exec /path/.../python3venv/bin/gunicorn
```